# Runtime of dynamic programming versus it's naive recursive counterpart

Tags: python, runtime, big-o, dynamic-programming, complexity-theory

The problem follows:

> You are playing a game where you start with n sticks in a pile (where n is a positive integer),
> and each turn you can take away exactly 1, 7, or 9 sticks from the pile (if there are fewer than 9
> sticks left, you can't choose that option, and similarly with 7). You want to know the minimum
> number of turns needed to reach 0 sticks.

And we're asked to implement a naive recursive solution and a O(n) dynamic programming solution, here's what I have:

```py
def take(pile, turns, cur):
    if cur > pile:
        return float("inf")    
    if cur == pile:
        return turns
    else: 
        res = 1 + min(take(pile, turns, cur+1), take(pile, turns,cur+7), take(pile, turns, cur+9))
        return res
```

And my DP solution

```py
def takeDP(pile, turns, cur):
    if cur > pile:
        return float("inf")
    if mem[cur] != float("inf"):
        return mem[cur]
    if cur == pile:
        return turns
    else: 
        res =  1 + min(takeDP(pile, turns, cur+9), takeDP(pile, turns,cur+7), takeDP(pile, turns, cur+1))
        if res < mem[cur]:
            mem[cur] = res 
        return res
```

When timing each, `takeDP` is much faster but I'm trying to bridge the gap of understanding the complexities of each. The best angle of attack I can think of is to compare the reduced recursion tree of `takeDP` compared to `take`'s, but I can't really express how `take`'s O(3^n) is optimized to O(n) enough to justify it in words. By virtue of this I'm also not entirely confident in my `takeDP` solution being correct.

Comment: So what you're asking is why does the DP approach result in O(n) complexity?

Comment: Either you should make the recursive calls with `turns + 1` instead of `turns` (and leave out the `1 +` before the `min`); or you should get rid of argument `turns` entirely. Notice how `turns` is never modified, so if it's 0 on the first call, it will always be 0, and so it's not needed at all. When `cur==pile` you can return `0` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the following observations, which are true for both functions:

- The only variable that changes between different recursive calls is `cur`;
- Initially `cur` is equal to `0`;
- `cur` can never be higher than `n`, the number of sticks in the pile.

From the above observations, you can conclude that there really are only `n+1` *different* calls that are ever made:

```
take(n, 0, 0), take(n, 0, 1), take(n, 0, 2), take(n, 0, 3), ..., take(n, 0, n)
```

So, if more than `n+1` calls are made in total, it must mean that the extra calls are redundant, *i.e.*, recalculating things that have already been calculated before.

The DP version makes sure that everytime a new different call is made, its return value is stored in array `mem`. And if two identical calls are made, then the second call is going to be interrupted immediately by the `if mem[cur] != float("inf"):` clause.

**So, with the DP version,** there can be at most `n+1` calls that are not interrupted by the `if mem[cur] != float("inf"):` clause. And each of these `n+1` calls spawn at most 3 calls, so you can immediately conclude that there will not be more than `4n+4` calls in total. In fact, a closer analysis would say that there is exactly `3n+4` calls. But anyway, even if you're only convinced that there cannot be more than `4n+4` calls, that's enough to conclude: the time-complexity of the DP version is **`O(n)`**.

**With the naive-recursive version though,** all we can say is that each recursive call spawns 3 new recursive calls, down to a depth of recursion of `n+1`, and therefore the total number of recursive calls is about **`3^n`**. Actually, each recursive branch has a depth somewhere between `n` and `n/9`, because `cur` is incremented by `1`, `7` or `9`. So we can conclude that the time-complexity of the naive-recursive version is somewhere between `3^n` and `3^(n/9) ≈ 1.13^n`. Anyway, even without a closer analysis, that's enough to conclude that the time-complexity of the naive-recursive version is exponential.